# Angular merge not working

Tags: angularjs

Using Angular 1.5.8.

I have a function other components call to keep the parent updated. The parent maintains the master copy of the entity being edited which I will call widget.  On init I set three fields on the widget

```
{a:Array[0],b: {},c:{}}
```

Once one of the components loads data via $resource it calls into the update function  with an Object that tries to set d.  When I print d in dev tools console it says  d is an object an when I expand it I get:

```
status: Resource
    x: "something"
    y: "something else"
```

next I call angular.toJson on d and get `{"status":{"x":"something","y":"something else"}}`

finally I call `angular.merge(widget,resultFromToJsonAbove)` and print the result I get back my original widget with no status object. When I experiment in a plunker with 1.5.8 and minimal example status gets added to widget.  Am I missing anything or overlooking something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

angular.toJson creates a string and you cannot merge a string onto an existing object, because angular.merge expects two objects (maps). You are calling it with an object and a string.

If you really want to do it this way, you will need to deserialize the string back to an object with angular.fromJson and pass that to merge.